# Using dead keys in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Here is a minimal example.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DeadKeyTextFieldExample extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField textField = new TextField();

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(textField);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Dead Key TextField Example");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

On Windows, the normal way to type a ñ is AltGr + ~ and n (at least on a Swedish keyboard). But when I do this in the text field the result is ~¨n. What can I do to get the expected behaviour?

EDIT: I am using JavaFX 20, Windows 10. I might add that other dead key characters work as expected: ¨ + e gives ë, ^ + e gives ê, but ~ + e gives ~ë.

Comment: I typed `Alt + 164` and got ñ in your sample app. `Windows 11 version 10.0 running on amd64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)`.

Comment: @SedJ601 Alt-numpad is not the normal way to type non-ASCII characters.  The title specifically mentions dead keys—that is, keystrokes which indicate a pending diacritical which will be applied to the next typed character (usually a letter).  You can see this for yourself by switching your Windows keyboard layout to “US international” or any other layout with dead keys and/or AltGr.

Comment: @VGR, thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: What version of JavaFX are you using?  I’ve found that support for native keyboard entry has varied a lot from one version of JavaFX to the other (and from one OS with slightly different sets of updates to another).  Can you try building and running the program with JavaFX 20?

Comment: As you state in your edit, it works as expected for some key combinations but not others, it is probably a bug, probably also platform specific.  Or it could just be that JavaFX only supports certain key combinations. You can [file a bug report](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/OpenJFX/Submitting+a+Bug+Report) or raise it on the openjfx-dev mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

This is a limited answer for a **Mac with testing using JavaFX 20**, it may not be exactly what you are looking for.

As noted by user VGR in comments, behavior will vary based based on your setup and actions.  For example, any of these can effect what happens:

- JavaFX version.
- OS type, version and setup.
- Keyboard hardware.
- Your applied text input procedure (sequence of keys typed).
- Installed and applied fonts.

I tried this on MacOS 13.4.1.  I used a MacBook Pro 2019 internal US keyboard with no special configurations in the OS for alternate input languages.

What I found, is:

- I type in a JavaFX TextField -> `Option + n`

  - it will display a `~` character.
- I subsequently type another `n`

  - The `~` character will change to a `ñ` character.

The native OS X TextEdit application works the same.

For an external windows keyboard attached to the same machine, the `Alt` key is used rather than the non-existent `Option` key.

To find out how to do this I followed the ["less common method" for Apple laptops](https://iamaileen.com/how-to-type-enye/#:%7E:text=%C2%BB%20Apple%20Computer%20or%20Laptop).  The "most common method" documented there only worked in the native app, not the JavaFX app. The "most common method" involves "Press and hold the letter “n” key and a small popup will appear", which doesn't happen with JavaFX, instead it starts firing the keyboard repeat and writes lots on n characters.

It could be that you are using an unexpected key combination for your platform (from the JavaFX perspective), which JavaFX isn't recognizing.  On another platform, with the correct platform-specific key combination used and recognized by JavaFX, the text input controls are able to correctly process the input and map it to the desired characters (as demoed for certain input sequences outlined in this answer).

**Other related info**

*Key combinations are relayed in `KEY_TYPED` events*

There is a (seemingly) related, but not the same, issue which was closed as not an issue: [JDK-8172104 Dead keys are not detected](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8172104), where it indicates that the actual outcome of the key combination comes in a [`KEY_TYPED` event](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#KEY_TYPED) (not a `KEY_PRESSED` event).

The related issue is just about correctly filtering keys. If the core platform is able to correctly recognized `KEY_TYPED` strings, then I am not sure why TextField would not use that by default in your case.  I did check the JavaFX source code internally and it seems to me that text input controls function based on `KEY_TYPED` strings.

*There are [dead keycodes](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/KeyCode.html#DEAD_TILDE)*

This means that the JavaFX system and key events can be made aware of [dead keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key).

If you can't get the default functionality to work as you want, perhaps you could intercept them in a filter, consume the relevant events, store the historic captured key input sequences somewhere, then, if you detect a sequence which should generate something you want, map that sequence to something which does actually generate the required output (such as generating synthetic keypress events based on numerics, which SedJ601 noted in comments seems to work). This seems tricky though, probably should be a better way, so I would only consider such an approach as a last resort.  Alternately, you could raise additional feature requests for the JavaFX development team.

**Test App**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class EnyaApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new TextField());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```