# JavaFX 21 TextField and Japanese input

Tags: javafx, textfield, cjk

I have a Java 21 desktop application with JavaFX and I want to support Japanese text input. No problem I guess with a Japanese keyboard, but I have problems (on Mac OS X) with keyboard emulation. I mean the かな assisted input like in the attached image:

[image: Japanese romaji input].

I would expect the input of japanese kana / kanji to happen normally, but it is instead erratic and it does not always work. Also, when browsing suggestions and clicking on one of them a message like "java[61157:14017992] Warning: Window move completed without beginning" is written on text output / error. Heh?

Has anyone faced the same issues?

With Windows IME input works better, but it's somehow peculiar how - normally - the japanese characters would appear directly in the text area / input field, while with JavaFX input fields the assisted input produces an additional tiny "window" with a preview of the japanese characters, and a confirm button. You must first enter the romaji from keyboard, choose the desired japanese characters in the windowlet and THEN have them in the text field. It works, though...

I wander if there's some catch with focus / events (my TextField is plain vanilla with no custom event handlers whatsoever anyway).

Comment: This isn't the same question, and is not an answer to your question, but you may be interested in some of the discussion for [Using dead keys in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76885894/using-dead-keys-in-javafx).  I think, because JavaFX is its own UI toolkit, it doesn't really hook into the native input handling for some different locales.  JavaFX has its own implementation (or sometimes not) for handling the keyboard input for those locales, which may differ from how the native OS works (in a way that is sometimes undesirable).